# Kill SSHFS at shutdown? (systemd / upstart)

Tags: shutdown, upstart, sshfs, mountpoint, systemd

Apparently having an SSHFS mountpoint active while trying to restart or shutdown Ubuntu can cause the system to hang. I would really like to avoid having to possibly power cycle, due to using an md soft RAID mirror array that could be corrupted.

There is a workaround listed here, but it is a shutdown/kill script for Systemd, which will be used in the future by Ubuntu, but is not yet implemented in 14.04 LTS:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sshfs#Shutdown_hangs_when_sshfs_is_mounted

How is the same thing accomplished using Upstart?

Comment: Are you manually mounting that sshfs? I think it will be auto unmounted if it was auto mounted (by fstab).

Comment: Yes, using a script to manually mount the remote sshfs, do some backups, and dismounting when done.

Answer (score 2):

Create `/etc/init/killsshfs.conf` file as root:

```
# killsshfs - 
#
# This service pkill sshfs 
description "pkill sshfs"
start on deconfiguring-networking
console log
task

exec /usr/bin/pkill sshfs
```

According to [**upstart wiki**](https://wiki.debian.org/Upstart#Network_dependencies):

> If you are converting a systemd service like this to an Upstart job,
>   deconfiguring-networking should be used as a stop on event.

In this case, when `deconfiguring-networking` event is emitted during shutdown, upstart starts `killsshfs` job that run `pkill sshfs` command before the network goes down.

This would be equivalent to [systemd killsshfs service](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sshfs#Shutdown_hangs_when_sshfs_is_mounted).